# What's this stuff on my Calendar month view?

Tags: 8.0, calendars

My calendar's month view seems to be cluttered with some really odd stuff, and I don't have a clue where it's coming from. There's labels on every date which seem to be written in another language.

They don't match anything that's visible on my day view, or in any of the Google calendars from which my phone should be pulling data. Everything in my Google calendar does show up in the day view, but nothing from the day view is visible on the month view.

The labels are so small, I can't even read them on my phone. I have to take a screenshot and read it on my computer monitor to even begin to figure out what they are. The phrases from the labels are below (all are approximations, as best as I was able to read them):

> Laecenas sem mattis
>   Suspendisse egetos
>   Diginiss milt
>   Class aptent tacitis
>   Iads honcus nis
>   Alquam sodale
>   Egestas nisi quis
>   Nulla facilis

One of those labels is on every day of the calendar in month view, and sometimes there's two. Screenshot is below.

[image]

What's causing this? How can I get rid of these, short of resetting my phone or doing anything else that might lose data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those texts are there to show to you in witch days you have appointments but they are not made to you really read them.

Since there isn't much space in those blocks they used those texts instead of a bar or dots to mark the day.

**Edit**

I had asked a long time ago the official Twitter support account but can't find it now. So I [asked again](https://twitter.com/vitor_canova/status/369493604214915072) and they pointed me to the [Microsoft Community site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpemail/in-microsoft-calendar-month-view-displays-a/48d1c5cd-1b6b-4924-af19-a4b46ce768b6?q6210595=1). The MVP @profjulie said:

"*The text you see in the monthly calendar view is gibberish and is just there to indicate you have entries on those days. You can tap a day where you see this gibberish and view the actual text and appointments that are scheduled for that day. This is the case for every windows phone and there is no way to change it*."

Comment: This is called the [Lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) text. It's basically massacred latin from cicero.